# PySpark SQL 'OR' condition working in unexpected manner with dates

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, where-clause

I am running queries on pyspark using pyspark sql but I am running into strange behavior.
I have where statement which looks like this:

```
WHERE `foobar`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
OR `foobar_2`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
```

Above where statement filters out all of my data which results in empty df but what is strange is that when I change from OR to AND I no longer get empty data frame but proper results which doesn't make sense to me as OR should be more inclusive? Is there a different operator for OR in pyspark sql?

**Empty df:**

```
spark.sql("""
select *
from `foobar`
full outer join `foobar_connector` on (`foobar_connector`.`some_id` = `foobar`.`other_id`)
full outer join `foobar_2` on (`foobar_connector`.`some_other_id` = `foobar_2`.`other_id`)
WHERE `foobar`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
OR `foobar_2`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
""").show()
```

**DF contains results:**

```
spark.sql("""
select *
from `foobar`
full outer join `foobar_connector` on (`foobar_connector`.`some_id` = `foobar`.`other_id`)
full outer join `foobar_2` on (`foobar_connector`.`some_other_id` = `foobar_2`.`other_id`)
WHERE `foobar`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
AND `foobar_2`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
""").show()
```

What could be a reason for this behaviour? According to my understanding if "AND condition" returns non-empty df then "OR condition" shouldn't return empty df, it should retrun the same number of records or more.

---

**UPDATE 1**

---

I have found out that if I change the statement from

```
WHERE `foobar`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
OR `foobar_2`.`business_date` = '2020-01-01'
```

to

```
WHERE `foobar`.`business_date` = DATE('2020-01-01')
OR `foobar_2`.`business_date` = DATE('2020-01-01')
```

then I get the expected behaviour but I have no idea why it works for AND without the need to explicitly convert